# Subungual Hematoma

Tags: trauma, nails, toe

My son dropped the edge of barstool in a straight line down his big toe. (One in a 1000 shot) his toenail immediately collected blood under 90% of the nail. The pain went away after five days and the doctor said leave it alone. It wasn't drained. The nail is now bleeding from under the cuticle 8 days after injury. 
Is this an indication of serious damage to the growing plate of the nail, indicative of permanent toenail loss? Cause for another Dr's visit? Or am I just overreacting?  TIA for any help.

Comment: Go to the doctor.